# How do I use a similar thing to splitlines() from python in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a list of `username:password` and I'm wanting to separate each of them, how would I be able to do like:

```js
let username = usernameValue;
let password = passwordValue;
```

So that I can have a big list of say 10+ username/password that my script can automatically pull from the txt file to then login into each individual account.

Comment: Don't edit in answers. If you have a problem with the answer, either state it in the comments of the answer, or ask another question.

Comment: Sorry, will do.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) this will take a string and split it into an array of sub-strings based off the given argument.

```js
const value = 'username:password';
const [usernameValue, passwordValue] = value.split(':');

console.log(usernameValue);
// 'username'

console.log(passwordValue);
// 'password'
```

Comment: Oh, will this be able to go through like for example:
`test:example newline
test2:example2`

Comment: Yes, the string will be split by a colon regardless of content

Comment: However you'll need to be able to individually access the entries

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have split lines first

```
var lines = text.match(/^.*((\r\n|\n|\r)|$)/gm);
```

and then

```
lines.map((i) => i.split(":"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the password and username from a string you need to split the line using [Split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```js
const acc = 'username:password'.split(':');

console.log(acc[0])
console.log(acc[1])
```

If you want it to read everyline of a txt file and split those and then console.log them you can do this

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./accounts/file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    data = data + '';
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    let account = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)];

    const acc = account.split(":");
    console.log(acc[0])
    console.log(acc[1])
})
```

additionally if you want to remove an account after you just grabbed one you can just remove it with [join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```
fs.writeFile('./accounts/file.txt', lines.slice(1).join('\n'), function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
});
```