# How to get more than 1 set of User:Pass from Accounts.txt

Tags: node.js, path, fs

I have a list of username:password and I'm wanting to separate each of them, how would I be able to do like:

```js
let username = usernameValue;
let password = passwordValue;
```

So that I can have a big list of say 10+ username/password that my script can automatically pull from the txt file to then login into each individual account.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const accounts = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./../../settings/accounts.txt'), 'utf8')
const [usernameValue, passwordValue] = accounts.split(':');

console.log(usernameValue);
// 'username'

console.log(passwordValue);
// 'password'
```

*Parts of the above code was taken from my original [question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69394004/14385064)*

*accounts.txt*

```yaml
test:test
test2:test2
test3:test3
```

***Output***

```yaml
test - username
test - password
test2 - username
```

It doesn't output every single value, and I don't have a clue why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is line by line you could use the package `readline`. For example:

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/accounts.txt"),
});

rl.on("line", (line) => {
    const [usernameValue, passwordValue] = line.split(':');
    console.log(`${usernameValue} - ${passwordValue}`);
});
```

If you want a delay between line output you could put an interval and process the info stored in a buffer:

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/accounts.txt"),
});

const buffer = [];
let isDonde = false;

rl.on("line", (line) => {
    buffer.push(line.split(':'));
});

rl.on("close", () => {
    isDonde = true;
})

let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (!buffer.length) {
        if (isDonde) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        return;
    }

    const [usernameValue, passwordValue] = buffer.shift();
    console.log(`${usernameValue} - ${passwordValue}`);
}, 1000); // higher is more time between logs
```

Comment: This did the trick but, it feeds out the lines so fast, is there a way to like slow it down per line?

Comment: @Johnty I Update the answer with a the second solution with the slow mode