# How would I go about only selecting a certain number of lines with this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, readline

How would I go about only selecting a certain number of lines with this code?
I have a rough understanding of using `line` but from that point I don't have a clue on how to ensure it only gets say for example 5 lines of accounts from the txt file or 10 accounts etc....

The code below is from a previous question I put on here: [How to get more than 1 set of User:Pass from Accounts.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69398101/14385064)

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/accounts.txt"),
});

rl.on("line", (line) => {
    const [username, password] = line.split(':');
    console.log(`${username}${password}`)
});
```

I've found a "Possible" solution but it doesn't stop counting when the number required is reached.

```js
const line_counter = ((i = 0) => () => ++i)();

rl.on("line", (line, num = line_counter()) => {
    console.log(num)
    if (num === 10) {
        const [username, password] = line.split(':');
        console.log(`${username}${password}`);
        console.log("10")
    }
    //extra code
})
```

*Little Explanation:*
I have a config system where it goes like so:

```js
config = {
        "yourroleid": 1500,
        "yourroleid": 75,
        "yourroleid": 50,
        "yourroleid": 20,
        "yourroleid": 10,
        "yourroleid": 5
    }
```

with this in mind, the person with said role(roleid) would only be able to get say for example 5 accounts or 10 accounts from the list.
and it would ONLY do that many instead of a continuous "spam" of accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the goal of exiting the readline early you are going to want to use the `for await (const line of target) {` syntax instead of the `.on("line",`  method.

```js
let limit = 0;
for await (const line of rl) {
    limit++;
    const [user, pass] = line.split(":");
    //do stuff
    if (limit === 10) break;
}
```

**Edited based on clarifying comments / conversation of goals**

Comment: This somewhat answers my question but I was looking for a more simplified answer, in the sense of like checking to see if the number is like 10 if so do whatever is required with those 10 accounts. I'll edit my question a little more to explain...

Comment: So from your example, you are looking to skip all entries that are not the 10th entry? Also the `for await` syntax happens in sequence, however the `.on` method is non-blocking. In a for loop you can use break to exit the loop if that is desired. You can use await to block the next process.

Comment: For example: I'm trying to get is so only a certain amount of accounts are logged in from whomever requested so say:
`Johnty` requested and only has roleid accessible to `20` accs, only login `20` accounts from the txt file.
`async await` requested and only has roleid accessible to `1500` accs, only login `1500` accounts from the txt file.

Comment: So client requests `x` number of rows from the file, and your function returns that number of rows starting from the beginning?

Comment: basically yes, client with desired roleid requests, and the script checks to see if that roleid matches, grabs the value from that matching roleid and then only grabs `x` amount of lines from the file does what it needs to do, Example: `client` has roleid `10`, the script checks if roleid matches `10`, selects the number from the json `10:10` and grabs those `10` from the file and logs them in.

Comment: Does my last edit help answer your question? Also, I would like to inject that this would be a good use case for a database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237804/discussion-between-johnty-and-async-await).